# biblatex combined with refsection and List of Tables

Tags: biblatex, table-of-contents

I have the following problem: Some Tables have captions with references in them. This works, however, when I add a List of tables (and I'm using biblatex with refsection=chapter), this reference gets messed up in the List of tables (i.e., I get ['2] instead of [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GR0Zr.png).

Is there a magic trick? Or can I even "hide" all the used references from captions in the List of Tables?

```
    \documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[refsection=chapter]{biblatex}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
\begin{filecontents}{biblio.bib}
@book{goossens93,
    author = "Michel Goossens and Frank Mittlebach and Alexander Samarin",
    title = "The Latex Companion A",
    year = "1993",
    publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
    address = "Reading, Massachusetts"

}

@article{greenwade93, 
    author = "George D. Greenwade",
    title = "The {C}omprehensive {T}ex {A}rchive {N}etwork ({CTAN})",
    year = "1993",
    journal = "TUGBoat",
    volume = "14",
    number = "3",
    pages = "342--351",
           url=" www.ctan.org"
}

\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{biblio.bib}

\begin{document}
\listoftables
\chapter{Test Chapter One}
\cite{goossens93}
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]

\chapter{Test Chapter Two}

\begin{table}
\caption{Tabelle mit \cite{goossens93}}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{lll}
    \hline
    \textbf{linke Spalte} & \textbf{mittlere Spalte} & \textbf{rechte Spalte} \\
    \hline
    i & ii & iii \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). I'm not sure what you mean by 'hide' here - your caption makes no sense without the reference.. `\caption[Caption for List of Tables]{Tabelle mit \cite{goossens93}}` would allow setting a different caption for the list of tables.

Comment: Hey. Thanks for the quick reply! That trick with [] could do the job for 'hiding' the reference in the list. But I still don't see the reason why it gives me ['2] in the first place...

Comment: Added the screenshots. I did a new install this week....(using miktex for windows)

Comment: Mhhhh, I think this has to do with the use of `refsections`. When you use `\cite` in the table, the cite is called in `refsection 2`, but when the caption is copied to the list of tables, the cite (issued and thought to have been originated and confined to section 2) suddenly appears in `refsection 0` - and that naturally causes havoc (especially in the auxiliary files and when trying to read those). The output `['1]` that you get is just LaTeX trying to make the best of a bad job, i.e. trying to get a reasonable output from a messed-up input.

Comment: So you could get rid of `refsection` (probably not what you want), or - as greyshade suggested - use the optional argument to caption to specify a shorter caption for the list of tables. (It would be weird to have the reference visible in the list of tables anyway if you have a per-chapter bibliography, as it just adds to the confusion on where to look up the reference. Normally, a reference in a table of ... / list of ... is not really of lot of use anway.)

Comment: I'll probably stick to the custom captions then. You're right, references in the list of tables is weird. Thanks everyone :-)