# biblatex + siunitx : Citation not working in list of figures when using refsection

Tags: biblatex, siunitx

I stumbled upon a problem where I have only the citation key in the list of figures when using the packages `biblatex` and `siunitx` at the same time with ref sections.

If you compile the working MWE just below, you get this in the figures' captions

- [image: Figure 1 caption when siunitx is commented]
- [image: Figure 2 caption when siunitx is commented]

And you get a correct list of figures at the end:

- [image: List of figures when siunitx is commented]

But if you *uncomment* the `\usepackage{siunitx}` line, you get the same thing in the figures' captions, but in the list of figures, you only get the citation key..

- [image: List of figures when using siunitx]

Any idea on how to get the list of figures working like in the first example, while using the `siunitx` package?

Thank you.

Tex file : `main.tex`

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{book}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{refsection}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\rule{2cm}{2cm}
\caption{The is the first caption \protect{\autocite{bertram}}}
\end{figure}

\printbibliography

\end{refsection}


\begin{refsection}
\newpage
\lipsum[2] \autocite{doody}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\rule{2cm}{2cm}
\caption{The is the second caption \protect{\autocite{aristotle:anima, doody}}}
\end{figure}

\printbibliography

\end{refsection}

\clearpage
\listoffigures



\end{document}
```

- PS : I'm not using siunitx in this MWE, but in my actual projet, i do need it.
- PS2: I'm compiling on Overleaf.
- Edit : I saw the question at [biblatex combined with refsection and List of Tables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/198002/biblatex-combined-with-refsection-and-list-of-tables) but it is without answer, and it does not cover the `siunitx` package part..
- Edit 2 : I adapted the MWE to not depend on images

Comment: Interesting question! A first look suggests the `.lof` looks different when `siunitx` is loaded: It is missing the `\defcounter {refsection}{1}\relax ` lines that `biblatex` patches in. But I'm not sure why. Will have to investigate that later...

Comment: Unrelated, note that you can make this into a single mwe by adding the bibtex data via the `filecontents` env in the preamble. It takes the filename to be created as its mandatory argument. Additionally, please don't refer to files we do not have access to (the image), you can use `\rule{5cm}{5cm}` instead

Comment: @moewe biblatex adds stuff to `\addtocontents` at the end of the preamble, and `siunitx` redefines it at begin document.

Comment: @daleif thank you for your advice regarding the MWE, i adapted it and removed the images, the graphicx and float packages that were not relevant to the problem, and i used `biblatex-examples`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Update

`biblatex` switched to an entirely different way of dealing with `.lof`, `.lot` etc. files in v3.17. The MWE should now work as desired.

If you are having a similar problem, update your system thoroughly and make sure you have got at least `biblatex` v3.17. If the problem persists, open an issue at https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/.

Some background for the issue can be found at https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/1116.

The answer below is kept for historic reasons. It will probably not work as intended in current versions of `biblatex` and it is definitely not needed.

---

### Old answer

As [daleif](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/3929/daleif) points out [in the comments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/588479/biblatex-siunitx-citation-not-working-in-list-of-figures-when-using-refsecti/588556#comment1478291_588479), `biblatex` patches `\addtocontents` in an `\AtEndPreamble` hook, but then `siunitx` redefines `\addtocontents` in an `\AtBeginDocument` hook, which also overwrites `biblatex`'s patch.

The following fix combines both `biblatex`'s and `siunitx`' changes to `\addtocontents` and comes in after both definitions.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\makeatletter
\ExplSyntaxOn
\AtBeginDocument
  {
    \cs_set:Npn \addtocontents #1#2
      {
        \protected@write \@auxout
          {
            \cs_set_eq:NN \label    \use_none:n
            \cs_set_eq:NN \index    \use_none:n
            \cs_set_eq:NN \glossary \use_none:n
            \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_siunitx_unit_symbolic_seq
              { \__siunitx_contents_add:N ##1 }
          }
          { 
            \token_to_str:N \@writefile {#1} {\defcounter{refsection}{\the\c@refsection}\relax}
            \token_to_str:N \@writefile {#1} {#2}
          }
      }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{refsection}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{example-image}
\caption{The is the first caption \autocite{bertram}}
\end{figure}

\printbibliography
\end{refsection}

\clearpage
\begin{refsection}
\lipsum[2] \autocite{doody}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{example-image}
\caption{The is the second caption \autocite{aristotle:anima, doody}}
\end{figure}

\printbibliography
\end{refsection}

\clearpage
\listoffigures
\end{document}
```

[image: LoF with citation numbers.]

Comment: Opened https://github.com/josephwright/siunitx/issues/408 to discuss the situation.

Comment: Joseph mentioned in the chat that perhaps it was time to move to hooks

Comment: Hello, this patch did it like a charm, thanks to you both moewe and @daleif for such a quick answer